# Xcode 11: IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool, Unable to create image for file

Tags: ios

I'm trying to run udacity course projects on xcode 11 emulator but it's failing with "**Unable to create image for file**" and "**Unable to get image dimensions for file**" for all image files in the project. 
The projects can be opened a run just fine in xcode 10.1.

How can this be solved?

github projects: https://github.com/udacity/ios-nd-uikit

> IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[27450:632191] Unable to get image
>   dimensions for file IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[27450:632191]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for file

Comment: do you have solution now?

Comment: I have no solution yet, probably because i'm running in a virtual machine? Need to try in the latest xcode version 11.1

Comment: Hi @Sergio, I am able to fix by updating Mac OS.

Comment: hello. Do we have any solution for this issue now?  I have this issue on XCode 11.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with Mac OS Catalina-Beta, able to fix by updating it to stable version. May be it can be fixed by update to new beta version, I mean it Cann't be a beta OS issue.

Hope it will help someone.